# Are ratios and percentages univariate or multivariate?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, anomaly-detection, percentage, ratio

**Edited**

I'm working on an anomaly detection project where I have a set of independent variables and dependent variables. As I have ratio and percentage data, I want to know how to document ratios and percentages, whether univariate or multivariate.

e.g.

- ratio = mass / volume
- percentage = mass of element / total mass

Comment: "Cardinality" means the *count.*  "Univariate" means *one* variable.  "Multivariate" means "one or more* variables.  Please explain, then, what you mean by the "cardinality" of a ratio or percentage and what it would mean to "document" such a thing.  Are you sure that "cardinality" and "document" are the right words to be using for your question?

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you @whuber! What I'm looking for here is to develop a report about KPIs where I indicate whether they are univariate or multivariate.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "documenting" ratios?  The sense in which you use "univariate" and "multivariate" remains obscure, because it doesn't seem to correspond to standard meanings of those terms.

Comment: I'm working on an anomaly detection project and wanted to know how to proceed with anomaly detection in ratio and percentage. Is it to consider them as one variable (univariate) or a combo of multiple variables (multivariate)? For the documentation part, I need to document this in my KPI analysis report before proceeding with the actual implementation.

Comment: It depends on what you might mean by an "anomaly."  The best methods of documenting data usually describe the data rather than derived quantities like ratios.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for your comments, I really appreciate the help. By anomaly, I mean outliers that diverge from the regularities in the data (the norm). I'm asking as I might integrate this derivation logic e.g. Ratio = a/b => Anomaly of ratio = anomaly of (a or b). Or do you think it's better to treat ratio as singular data and study its outliers independently of its constructors (a and b). Please correct me if I'm using any inappropriate statical lexicon!